# Xamarin Forms Portable Class Library App Working on Android but not on iOS as expected

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

A Xamarin Forms PCL application is rendering but none of the controls are working on iOS platform (tested on iPhone 7 running 12.4.1)

The app has been fully tested and functional on the Google Android platform and I am now trying to get it to work on Apple iOS platform as well.

```
        configurationTypeLabel.Text = "What configuration type is being set?";
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(configurationTypeLabel);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(configurationTypePicker);
        configurationTypePicker.Items.Add("FTP Configuration");
        configurationTypePicker.Items.Add("Email Configuration");
        databaseNameLabel.Text = "Database Name";
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(databaseNameLabel);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(databaseNamePicker);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(addNewDatabaseName);
        mainStackLayout.Children.Add(addNewDatabaseButton);
        addNewDatabaseButton.Text = "Input New Database Name";
        serverNameLabel.Text = "Server Name";
```

The app allows for data input and is rendered dynamically is expected but the controls event though they have been rendered they are all disabled.

Comment: Can you share your sample?

Comment: Try using MainThread to add your views.